# DB2 - Select count(*) not working properly on subquery

Tags: group-by, count, subquery, db2-luw

Here follows **2 querys** that should bring the **same result**, but unfortunately thats not the case. They have just **1 different line**:

1.

Result = **403**

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT CONSULTORA.ID CONSULTORA_ID, FIDC.ID FIDC_ID
        FROM public.PESSOA CONSULTORA, public.PESSOA FIDC, public.PESSOA_NEO4J pnj
        WHERE ((pnj.CNPJ = CONSULTORA.CPF_CNPJ AND pnj.FK_ID_FIDC = FIDC.ID)
                OR (pnj.CNPJ = FIDC.CPF_CNPJ AND pnj.FK_ID_FACTORING = CONSULTORA.ID))
            AND CONSULTORA.TIPO = 'EC'
            AND CONSULTORA.TIPO_ENTIDADE_CREDITO IN ('FACTORING', 'SECURITIZADORA')
            AND FIDC.TIPO = 'EC'
            AND FIDC.TIPO_ENTIDADE_CREDITO = 'FIDC'
        GROUP BY CONSULTORA.ID, FIDC.ID)
```

2. 

Result = **946**

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT CONSULTORA.ID CONSULTORA_ID, FIDC.ID FIDC_ID
        FROM public.PESSOA CONSULTORA, public.PESSOA FIDC, public.PESSOA_NEO4J pnj
        WHERE ((pnj.CNPJ = CONSULTORA.CPF_CNPJ AND pnj.FK_ID_FIDC = FIDC.ID)
                OR (pnj.CNPJ = FIDC.CPF_CNPJ AND pnj.FK_ID_FACTORING = CONSULTORA.ID))
            AND CONSULTORA.TIPO = 'EC'
            AND CONSULTORA.TIPO_ENTIDADE_CREDITO IN ('FACTORING', 'SECURITIZADORA')
            AND FIDC.TIPO = 'EC'
            AND FIDC.TIPO_ENTIDADE_CREDITO = 'FIDC'
        GROUP BY CONSULTORA.ID, FIDC.ID
        ORDER BY CONSULTORA.ID, FIDC.ID) -- Different Line
```

**Execution Plan [1]**:

```
Return      1   1.000   162.709
    Group By        2   1.000   162.708
        Table Queue     3   1.000   162.708
            Group By        4   0.000   162.688
                Group By        5   0.000   162.688
                    Table Scan      6   0.000   162.688
                        Sort        7   0.000   162.688
                            Nested loop Join        8   0.023   162.687
                                Fetch       20  137,293.000 14.305
                                    [NULL]  TA: PUBLIC.PESSOA_NEO4J [NULL]  137,293.000 [NULL]
                                    RID Scan        21  0.026   14.121
                                        Sort        24  0.026   7.061
                                            Index scan      25  137,293.000 7.060
                                                [NULL]  IX: DB2INST1.PESSOA_NEO4J_CNPJ_IDX3 [NULL]  137,293.000 [NULL]
                                        Sort        22  0.000   7.061
                                            Index scan      23  137,293.000 7.060
                                                [NULL]  IX: DB2INST1.PESSOA_NEO4J_CNPJ_IDX2 [NULL]  137,293.000 [NULL]
                                Rebalance rows between SMP subagents        9   0.023   141.520
                                    Hash Join       10  0.235   141.520
                                        Fetch       16  9,083,719.000   70.776
                                            [NULL]  TA: PUBLIC.PESSOA   [NULL]  9,083,719.000   [NULL]
                                            RID Scan        17  1,742.000   8.379
                                                Sort        18  1,742.000   8.379
                                                    Index scan      19  9,083,719.000   7.886
                                                        [NULL]  IX: DB2INST1.PESSOA_TIPO_IDX    [NULL]  9,083,719.000   [NULL]
                                        Rebalance rows between SMP subagents        11  0.235   70.744
                                            Fetch       12  9,083,719.000   70.743
                                                [NULL]  TA: PUBLIC.PESSOA   [NULL]  9,083,719.000   [NULL]
                                                RID Scan        13  1,742.000   8.379
                                                    Sort        14  1,742.000   8.379
                                                        Index scan      15  9,083,719.000   7.886
                                                            [NULL]  IX: DB2INST1.PESSOA_TIPO_IDX    [NULL]  9,083,719.000   [NULL]
```

**Execution Plan [2]**

```
Return      1   1.000   162.708
    Group By        2   0.000   162.708
        Group By        3   0.000   162.708
            Table Queue     4   0.000   162.708
                Group By        5   0.000   162.688
                    Nested loop Join        6   0.023   162.688
                        Fetch       19  137,293.000 14.305
                            [NULL]  TA: PUBLIC.PESSOA_NEO4J [NULL]  137,293.000 [NULL]
                            RID Scan        20  0.026   14.121
                                Sort        23  0.026   7.061
                                    Index scan      24  137,293.000 7.060
                                        [NULL]  IX: DB2INST1.PESSOA_NEO4J_CNPJ_IDX3 [NULL]  137,293.000 [NULL]
                                Sort        21  0.000   7.061
                                    Index scan      22  137,293.000 7.060
                                        [NULL]  IX: DB2INST1.PESSOA_NEO4J_CNPJ_IDX2 [NULL]  137,293.000 [NULL]
                        Table Scan      7   0.023   141.521
                            Sort        8   0.023   141.520
                                Hash Join       9   0.235   141.520
                                    Fetch       15  9,083,719.000   70.776
                                        [NULL]  TA: PUBLIC.PESSOA   [NULL]  9,083,719.000   [NULL]
                                        RID Scan        16  1,742.000   8.379
                                            Sort        17  1,742.000   8.379
                                                Index scan      18  9,083,719.000   7.886
                                                    [NULL]  IX: DB2INST1.PESSOA_TIPO_IDX    [NULL]  9,083,719.000   [NULL]
                                    Rebalance rows between SMP subagents        10  0.235   70.744
                                        Fetch       11  9,083,719.000   70.743
                                            [NULL]  TA: PUBLIC.PESSOA   [NULL]  9,083,719.000   [NULL]
                                            RID Scan        12  1,742.000   8.379
                                                Sort        13  1,742.000   8.379
                                                    Index scan      14  9,083,719.000   7.886
                                                        [NULL]  IX: DB2INST1.PESSOA_TIPO_IDX    [NULL]  9,083,719.000   [NULL]
```

Running only the **subquery**, the row count is actually **946** (so the **second query** is **right**).

I guess DB2 does not support **count** over **subquery** with same table **twice** (public.PESSOA) plus **GROUP BY**.

Do you guys went through the same situation? Is the syntax of **first query** incorrect? Or probably there is a bug in DB2?

Comment: Please, attach both access plans (from db2exfmt) here.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I dont have permission to access db2exfmt (only IBM admin has), instead I've attached DBeaver execution plans. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a Case with IBM support on this.